# How did I resolve the Vue 2 error with Node 12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, sass, node-sass

**Node 12** has an error with the **node-sass** library.

**Node is returning the following error:**

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0):

**node-sass** has been updated to fix the error. Now you can update **node-sass** to the latest version compatible with **Node 12** and resolve the problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass/v/4.12.0

**Happy coding again!**